# Can I avoid using stripe connect and just ask for my users to put their public stripe token in the app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, e-commerce, payment

so I have a web app that lets my users to create their catalog in it. So eventually there is admin dashboard and public facing url that their clients can see and where they can put items that this page has into their cart.

Cart itself only displays stuff that user picked and doesn't let them pay for it. But I'm thinking to add pay button in there via stripe.

And so the problem is that stripe offers this thing called stripe connect which is kinda what I'm looking for but it's a bit too complicated. So I was thinking maybe there is a way to skip it by asking catalog owners to put their stripe public key in the catalog and then I'll use it on the cart page like documentation says:

so my concern is if it'll be a big security issue or will it even work. And if it won't work, is there any way to simplify stripe connect thing?

I was also thinking to add option for my clients to put their payment link and then somehow customise payment link query parameter with the amount that needs to be paid but it doesn't seem to be supported.

So yeah, would be great to hear if someone had experience with that and what can I do to make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition Secret Key and Publishable Key is a pair, and only understands each other if they are on the same account. Even if you have your catalog owner's Publishable Key, you won't be able to process Stripe objects generated from your account's Secret Key.

Stripe Connect is the correct path forward where you can make 2 account "understands" each other (more accurately, your account to understand your catalog owner's account), and then you can share some portion of the sale to the catalog owner.

I would recommend [Destination Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges), keeping your catalog owner account as an *Express Connected Account*, for the simplest setup.